# Syncing MySQL and PHP times

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timezone

I am trying to sync my PHP and MySQL times. Currently the times are different (outputs below):

```
'SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' returns '2013-03-16 13:14:28'
'date('Y-m-d g:i:s')'      returns '2013-03-16 10:14:28'
```

I have had success, reading from other users, on changing the MySQL time using `SET time_zone='-7:00';`. The problem is the time will be changing for different queries based on the user's location and I would rather not change the `time_zone` for every query.

Should I just set the `time_zone` once, making it the same time as the server, and then change the time based on the user's timezone in PHP? Or is there a better way to go about this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I just set the time_zone once, making it the same time as the server, and then change the time based on the user's timezone in PHP? Or is there a better way to go about this?

Yes. You also ought not to set timezones via their GMT zone because of daylight savings time. You can write yourself functions to do this conversion by setting date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); and then to your user's timezone.

```
$time = strtotime('2013-03-16 13:14:28'.' UTC');
echo date('Y-m-d g:i:s',$time); //2013-03-16 9:14:28
```

Another alternative is to store mysql times in "Unix Time" and then convert only once with PHP.

Comment: Ohhh I like the idea of storing them in Unix Time and then doing the convert everytime. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want to use a single timezone in your application/database.  Only change the timezone of the data (not in the db or your php default tz) if you have to like when displaying to the user - and then only do that right before you about to display it.  otherwise, use a single timezone.  I prefer GMT

to set the mysql server timezone:  in my.conf
have somehthing like this:  `default-time-zone='GMT'`
and then restart mysql
see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

For php, somewhere at the top of each page you should execute this line:

```
date_default_timezone_set("GMT");
```

Comment: How would go about making correct dates that are already set in the DB which were set with the incorrect timezone?

Comment: you need to update any dates in your database with the date in the proper timezone.  You can only do this if you know what the previous timezone was.  UPDATE db.table set `date` = CONVERT_TZ(`date`, 'old tz', 'GMT')

Comment: Thanks for the tip on converting the dates!